# Exercise 2.7 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> **Exercise 2.7** Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ be subsets of a metric space.
>
> (a). If $B=\cup_{i=1}^n{A_i}$, prove that $\overline{B}=\cup_{i=1}^n{\overline{A_i}}$ for $n=1,2,3,..$
>
> (b). If $B=\cup_{i=1}^\infty{A_i}$, prove that $\overline{B}\supset\cup_{i=1}^\infty{\overline{A_i}}$ for $n=1,2,3,..$
>
> Note. $\overline{B}$ is the closure of $B$.

**Question 1.** I know how to prove (a). We got $\overline{E\cup{F}}=\overline{E}\cup\overline{F}$ first, and (a) is proved immediately.
But why we can't prove $\overline{B}=\cup_{i=1}^\infty{\overline{A_i}}$ with the same reason?

**Question 2.** Starting from (b). Suppose $A_i=\{r_i\}$, $r_i$ is a rational number. Then $B=\cup_{n=1}^\infty{A_i}$ is set of all the rational numbers, and $A_i=\overline{A_i}$. So, what is the $\overline{B}$?

Comment: The problem in b is that the union of closures might not be closed, when in the finite case it always is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you give in Question 2 answers Question 1.  Things that work for finite situations often don't work in infinite situations.    A smaller example for part b) would be to let $A_n = \{1/n\}$ for $n = 1, 2, \ldots.$  Then the closure of $B$ contains $0$, while $\cup \overline{A}_n$ does not.

Comment: So, the infinite union of $A_n$ get a limit point $0$, but the finite union of $A_n$ still has no limit point. So the infinite is like a magic makes things all different?

Comment: If you studied series, you probably saw that commutativity and associativity of addition can be ruined by infinity.  How can we evaluate $1-1+1-1+1-\cdots$?  One way:  $(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots = 0 + 0 + \cdots =0.$  Another way: $1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots = 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 1.$  Associativity doesn't work.

Comment: This is a nice example. And this example also ruin the commutativity, right?Cause $-1+(1-1)+(1-1)+...=-1$

Comment: Yep.  And since you have infinitely many $1$'s and $-1$'s, you can even do something like $1+(-1)+1+1+(-1) + 1+1+1+(-1) +\cdots = (1+(-1))+(1+1+(-1)) + (1+1+1+(-1)) +\cdots = 0 + 1 + 2+ 3 + \cdots = \infty.$

Comment: LOL. It's interesting. Thanks for your explanation. It's a great help!

Comment: BTW, why $\overline B$ is the set of all the real numbers

Comment: If you pick any real number, you can find a sequence of rational numbers which converges to it.  E.g., pick $\pi$.  Then a sequence that works is $3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, \ldots.$

Comment: So, what's the limit points of the set of all the rational numbers. I think the rational number itself is the limit point the set of all the rational numbers because the rational numbers are dense. And every irrational numbers are also the limit points of the rational numbers set. Right?@B. Goddard

Comment: If you're saying that every real number is a limit point of the set of rationals, then you're right.